# Tkinter pack after destroying

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy, pack

Just a simple example of a problem I experienced:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
label = Label(frame, text = "Hey")
label.pack()

def packframe():
    frame.pack()
def destroyframe():
    frame.destroy()

pack_button = Button(root, text = "pack", command = packframe)
pack_button.pack()

des_button = Button(root, text = "destroy", command = destroyframe)
des_button.pack()
```

Once I press the destroy button, I cannot pack it back again on the screen with the pack_button. Im not sure why is it so, but I would appreciate both explanaition and a solution

Comment: The frame is destroyed and cannot be packed again.  Use `pack_forget()` instead of `destroy()`.

Comment: When you call .destroy(), the widget is _destroyed_. That means it no longer exists.